# css flexbox grid with hover on flexbox cells (nested) does and does not work

Tags: html, css, hover, flexbox

The **:hover** behaviour in this example is making me doubt my sanity as everything in the code seems ok and works as expected, **except the hovering** of the **white cells** in the large matrix.

The generic structure has **2 flexbox `div` rows where:**

- row one has 2 small flexbox `div` 3by3 matrixes (2 puzzles each with 9 cells)
- row two has 1 large flexbox `div` 3by3 matrix of nine flexbox `ul` 3by3 matrixes (9 puzzles each with 9 cells )
- all tags (`div`, `ul` and `li`) are flexbox containers
- even/odd cells have different colors (white and grey)

The layouts have been copied from real Sudoku puzzles for this question (sorry, i don't have the solutions).

**To reproduce the problem**

- Hover the small puzzles and the grey puzzles of the large matrix. On hover, each cell gets colored `CornflowerBlue.`
- Hover the white cells of the large matrix and **only the full puzzle** gets colored `CornflowerBlue` **instead of each of the 9 cells** individually.

**The Question**

Please tell me, have I stumbled over some CSS bug (probably not) or is the solution (which?) staring me in the face and do I just not see my mistake?

**The Code**
(A bit long, but fully commented and with a few nifty responsiveness tricks...)

```css
/*****************************/
/* MINIMAL REQUIRED [STABLE] */
/*****************************/
/* [MANDATORY] for '.fbl-cell' to work */
html,body           { box-sizing: border-box }
::before,:after, *  { box-sizing: inherit }

/* remove default markup */
ul  { margin: 0; padding: 0 }
li  { list-style-type: none }

/**************************************/
/* easy RESPONSIVE|FONT|NESS [STABLE] */
/**************************************/
/* Math: y=mx+b for points p1(320,14) p2(1280,20) => 14>20 */
html        { font-size: calc(0.00625 * 100vmin + 12px) }    /* device dependend (not W/H), so use VMIN */
[lang="ar"] { font-size: calc(0.00625 * 100vmin + 15px) }    /* 17>23 (Arabic looks a bit small at 14>20) */
body        { font-size: 1rem; line-height: 1.5; margin: 0 } /* HTML default 16px/1.3/10px (or so) */

/***************************************/
/* GRID RESTRAINTS and MARKUP [STABLE] */
/***************************************/
/* main container */
.sudoku-row {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    justify-content: center;
    padding: .5rem;

    max-width: 100vmin;
    margin: 3rem auto;
}
/* cell container (default size) */
.sudoku-row>.sudoku {
    height: 10rem;
    width : 10rem;
    margin: .5rem;

    font-size: calc(0.00625 * 100vmin + 18px); /* responsive: (320,20)(1280,26) */
}
.sudoku.fullsize  { /* large size override */
    height: 75vmin;
    width : 75vmin;
    margin: 0 auto;

    font-size: calc(0.025 * 100vmin + 6px);   /* responsive: (320,14)(1280,38) */
}
/* hover */
.sudoku,.sudoku.fullsize>* {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
[fbl-cell]>:hover,.sudoku li:hover {
    background: CornflowerBlue;
    cursor: pointer;
}
/* coloring/styling */
body {
    background-color: #f0f0f0;
}
.sudoku-row>.sudoku {
    background: #fff;
}
.sudoku>:nth-child(even)  {
    background-color: #eee;
}
.sudoku li {
    border: 1px solid hsla(0,0%,0%,.15);
}

/*********************************************/
/* FLEXBOX and PATCH GRID STRUCTURE [STABLE] */
/*********************************************/
/* Both parent end child are flexbox containers */
[fbl-cell],[fbl-cell]>* {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
[fbl-cell] {
    align-content: flex-start;
}
[fbl-cell]>* { /* cell immediate child elements */
    flex: 1; /* allow grow (and shrink, which is HTML default as is 'flex-basis: auto') */
    overflow: hidden; /* [MANDATORY] */

    /* [DEMO] center content hor/vert inside cell */
    justify-content: center; align-items: center;
}
[fbl-cell="3x3"]>* { /* 3by3 matrix equally divided over parent space */
    flex-basis: 33.33333%; max-width : 33.33333%; /* 'width' won't work */
    height    : 33.33333%; max-height: 33.33333%;
}
```

```html
    <div class="sudoku-row">
        <ul fbl-cell="3x3" class="sudoku"><li> <li>9<li> <li>4<li><li>1<li> <li> <li>3</ul>
        <ul fbl-cell="3x3" class="sudoku"><li>2<li> <li>5<li> <li><li> <li> <li> <li> </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="sudoku-row">
        <div fbl-cell="3x3" class="sudoku fullsize">
            <ul fbl-cell="3x3"><li> <li>9<li> <li>4<li><li>1<li> <li> <li>3</ul>
            <ul fbl-cell="3x3"><li>2<li> <li>5<li> <li><li> <li> <li> <li> </ul>
            <ul fbl-cell="3x3"><li> <li>1<li> <li>3<li><li>9<li>6<li> <li> </ul>
            <ul fbl-cell="3x3"><li> <li> <li>3<li> <li><li> <li>9<li> <li> </ul>
            <ul fbl-cell="3x3"><li>4<li> <li>8<li> <li><li> <li>6<li> <li>1</ul>
            <ul fbl-cell="3x3"><li> <li> <li>5<li> <li><li> <li> <li> <li>7</ul>
            <ul fbl-cell="3x3"><li> <li> <li>9<li>6<li><li>7<li> <li>3<li> </ul>
            <ul fbl-cell="3x3"><li> <li> <li> <li> <li><li> <li>7<li> <li>9</ul>
            <ul fbl-cell="3x3"><li>1<li> <li> <li>4<li><li>2<li> <li>8<li> </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the `hover` rule/selector to

```
[fbl-cell]>li:hover,.sudoku > ul li:hover {
    background: CornflowerBlue;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```css
/*****************************/
/* MINIMAL REQUIRED [STABLE] */
/*****************************/
/* [MANDATORY] for '.fbl-cell' to work */
html,body           { box-sizing: border-box }
::before,:after, *  { box-sizing: inherit }

/* remove default markup */
ul  { margin: 0; padding: 0 }
li  { list-style-type: none }

/**************************************/
/* easy RESPONSIVE|FONT|NESS [STABLE] */
/**************************************/
/* Math: y=mx+b for points p1(320,14) p2(1280,20) => 14>20 */
html        { font-size: calc(0.00625 * 100vmin + 12px) }    /* device dependend (not W/H), so use VMIN */
[lang="ar"] { font-size: calc(0.00625 * 100vmin + 15px) }    /* 17>23 (Arabic looks a bit small at 14>20) */
body        { font-size: 1rem; line-height: 1.5; margin: 0 } /* HTML default 16px/1.3/10px (or so) */

/***************************************/
/* GRID RESTRAINTS and MARKUP [STABLE] */
/***************************************/
/* main container */
.sudoku-row {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    justify-content: center;
    padding: .5rem;

    max-width: 100vmin;
    margin: 3rem auto;
}
/* cell container (default size) */
.sudoku-row>.sudoku {
    height: 10rem;
    width : 10rem;
    margin: .5rem;

    font-size: calc(0.00625 * 100vmin + 18px); /* responsive: (320,20)(1280,26) */
}
.sudoku.fullsize  { /* large size override */
    height: 75vmin;
    width : 75vmin;
    margin: 0 auto;

    font-size: calc(0.025 * 100vmin + 6px);   /* responsive: (320,14)(1280,38) */
}
/* hover */
.sudoku,.sudoku.fullsize>* {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
[fbl-cell]>li:hover,.sudoku > ul li:hover {
    background: CornflowerBlue;
    cursor: pointer;
}
/* coloring/styling */
body {
    background-color: #f0f0f0;
}
.sudoku-row>.sudoku {
    background: #fff;
}
.sudoku>:nth-child(even)  {
    background-color: #eee;
}
.sudoku li {
    border: 1px solid hsla(0,0%,0%,.15);
}

/*********************************************/
/* FLEXBOX and PATCH GRID STRUCTURE [STABLE] */
/*********************************************/
/* Both parent end child are flexbox containers */
[fbl-cell],[fbl-cell]>* {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
[fbl-cell] {
    align-content: flex-start;
}
[fbl-cell]>* { /* cell immediate child elements */
    flex: 1; /* allow grow (and shrink, which is HTML default as is 'flex-basis: auto') */
    overflow: hidden; /* [MANDATORY] */

    /* [DEMO] center content hor/vert inside cell */
    justify-content: center; align-items: center;
}
[fbl-cell="3x3"]>* { /* 3by3 matrix equally divided over parent space */
    flex-basis: 33.33333%; max-width : 33.33333%; /* 'width' won't work */
    height    : 33.33333%; max-height: 33.33333%;
}
```

```html
<div class="sudoku-row">
        <ul fbl-cell="3x3" class="sudoku"><li> <li>9<li> <li>4<li><li>1<li> <li> <li>3</ul>
        <ul fbl-cell="3x3" class="sudoku"><li>2<li> <li>5<li> <li><li> <li> <li> <li> </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="sudoku-row">
        <div fbl-cell="3x3" class="sudoku fullsize">
            <ul fbl-cell="3x3"><li> <li>9<li> <li>4<li><li>1<li> <li> <li>3</ul>
            <ul fbl-cell="3x3"><li>2<li> <li>5<li> <li><li> <li> <li> <li> </ul>
            <ul fbl-cell="3x3"><li> <li>1<li> <li>3<li><li>9<li>6<li> <li> </ul>
            <ul fbl-cell="3x3"><li> <li> <li>3<li> <li><li> <li>9<li> <li> </ul>
            <ul fbl-cell="3x3"><li>4<li> <li>8<li> <li><li> <li>6<li> <li>1</ul>
            <ul fbl-cell="3x3"><li> <li> <li>5<li> <li><li> <li> <li> <li>7</ul>
            <ul fbl-cell="3x3"><li> <li> <li>9<li>6<li><li>7<li> <li>3<li> </ul>
            <ul fbl-cell="3x3"><li> <li> <li> <li> <li><li> <li>7<li> <li>9</ul>
            <ul fbl-cell="3x3"><li>1<li> <li> <li>4<li><li>2<li> <li>8<li> </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Argh, I know it had to be something obvious. And now having a fresh look at it adding `.sudoku>:nth-child(odd) { background-color: #fff }` would have worked too, but obfuscated the 'oversight/error' even more. Thanks!

Comment: Actually, changing the hover rule to `[fbl-cell]>:hover {cursor: pointer; background: hsla(219,79%,66%,.5); /* CornflowerBlue */ }
` would have shown that I was hovering both parent (white) and child (transparent) and did not see that because of the hover color.